# What was George August Imprisoned For?

Tags: england, palaeography

I've come across a log on Ancestry.co.uk which shows that George August was imprisoned in 1854. Below is a screenshot of the entry.

[image: Imprisonment log for George August]

I have managed to read it as follows, but this could be wrong as I can't seem to make sense of it:

```
Name: George August
Crime Tried for: Forgery _ a *equest for the Delius of Good _ 2 Con***t***
```

The original scan is available [here](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/iexec?htx=View&r=5538&dbid=1590&iid=31251_A006109-00218&fn=George&ln=August&st=r&ssrc=gr_t20403096_p20306263071_ktidz0q3d20403096z0q26pidz0q3d20306263071z0q26hidz0q3d33739002097z0q26dbidz0q3d1590z0q26rpidz0q3d1540657z0q26ssrcz0q3dgrz0q26pgz0q3d32799z0q252c32842z0q26pgplz0q3dtidz0q257cpidz0q257chidz0q257cdbidz0q257crpidz0q257cssrcz0q26pgpsz0q3d20306263071_h33739002097&pid=1540657).

Any other information needed, I will try to provide.

Comment: Could you provide a picture with more of the surrounding entries? Often it is helpful to see other handwriting by the same clerk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the first bit is "Forgery - a request for the delivery of goods" and the bit at the end is probably "2 convictions" but it's hard to be sure of that.

Comment: I agree it's very likely "2 convictions".  There's a couple of similar entries (less squashed) further down the page.

Comment: I also see "Forgery - a request for the Delivery of goods-2 convictions"

Answer (score 5):

The report of a [similar (1854) case at the Old Bailey](http://www.oldbaileyonline.org/browse.jsp?div=t18540130-241) shows that the offence was one which would be described in modern parlance as "false pretences" but which was dealt with as forging and uttering in the nineteenth century (*The fraudulent making or altering of a written document to the detriment of another man's right. Includes fraudulently copying or counterfeiting documents other than money, such as stamps or bonds.*).

Given that George was sent down for 9 months when other cases got as few as 3 months, it is possible that the judge took account of his previous record - 2 (prior) convictions. It may be worth searching before 1854 for the beginning of his larcenous activities (and after, on the assumption that he was a career criminal).